# How to reconfigure zabbix?

Tags: compilation, installation, package, zabbix

I already installed Zabbix server from packages. Some docs/tutorial said to configure again When I have to install services such as odbc. How can I use **./configure** command.

PS : I'm using zabbix in **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks this link will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `./configure` command, you should download Zabbix from the official website and install from sources. Please see [installation instructions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install) for more information on installing Zabbix from source.

Alternatively, you can install Zabbix packages from the official repository (see the [official download page](http://www.zabbix.com/download.php)). Packages for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty) seem to include support for ODBC checks.

Comment: Seen, I can't use **./configure** if I was installed from packages. Right?

Comment: Correct. Packages come with ready-made binaries, but ./configure affects how the source code is built.